# Remove table cells in html

Tags: html

In this example table i want to remove the borders from the bottom empty cells, tried to use in the css the `border-collapse:collapse;` but without success.

```
<table id="tableID" border="1">
<tr width="80px" height="50px">
<td width="80px" height="50px">asdasdasdasdasdasd</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">asdasda</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">sadsadasd</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">sadsadasd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="80px" height="50px">sasas</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">sdsadsa</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">sadasd</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">sdasd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"></td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">asas</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">aaaas</td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">ssssssa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td width="80px" height="50px">aaaas</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. `#tableID {border-collapse: collapse;}` removes the double border for the whole table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/15mjmy4j/

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

This looks nicer I think. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/15mjmy4j/1/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

Comment: Yes the first one, because if i take the second, in my option the user might think thats expected data to be there.

Comment: @changez cool, glad to help. if you feel this answer was sufficient I would not mind it being accepted. =]